# How to load a div first and then load the other ones?

Tags: html, css

I have a one page website and I want a div to be loaded first and then the second one and... Can I do this just with html and css? Or it needs JavaScript or...?

Comment: Depends what you want from the loading procedure. Are you wanting to put loader graphics while the div loads? If you just want them sequentially the answer has been posted. If you want loading bars etc as well as load sequentially, it gets more complicated ie- needs JS and some good coding habits :)

Comment: Is it possible with html and css? Learning JavaScript is for next step.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write the code sequentially:

```
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
```

the second div will be loaded after first, there is no more magic about this

Comment: No, I mean when the contents of div one are loading, at the same time the content of other divs are loading too.